# Search bar with working filter on items from json

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to make a filter bar that will work with a search bar. My data is in from json format containing artist,title, src, etc. I can't really figure it out how to make it work properly. I got my results in console.log, but I'm stuck with making it visible in the search result box.

```
const results = document.querySelector(".search-results");
for (let i = 0; i < allMusic.length; i++) {
  let result = `<li li-index="${i + 1}" onclick="clicked(this)">
                <div class="result-box">
                  <div class="result-box-cover">
                  <h1 class="result-name">${allMusic[i].name}</h1>
                  <p class="result-artist">${allMusic[i].artist}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <audio class="${allMusic[i].src}" src="songs/${allMusic[i].src}.mp3"></audio>
              </li>`;
  results.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", result);
}

function searchName() {
  input = document.getElementById('search-item');
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementsByClassName("search-results");
  li = document.querySelectorAll('.search-results li');

  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    nameResult = li[i].getElementsByClassName("result-name")[0];
    artistResult = li[i].getElementsByClassName("result-artist")[0];
    webkitresults = document.getElementsByClassName("search-results")[0];
    nameResult = nameResult.textContent || nameResult.innerText;
    artistResult = artistResult.textContent || artistResult.innerText;
    if (nameResult.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
      li[i].style.visibility = "visible";
      webkitresults.classList.remove("webkit-hidden");
    }
    else if (artistResult.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
      li[i].style.visibility = "visible";
      webkitresults.classList.remove("webkit-hidden");
    }
    else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
      li[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
    }


    if (input.value.length == 0)
    {
      li[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
      webkitresults.classList.add("webkit-hidden");
    }
  }
}

function filterByName() {
  if (filterStatus.classList.contains("Hip-Hop")) {
    var result = allMusic.filter((x)=>x.style === "Hip-Hop");
    console.log(result);
  }
  if (filterStatus.classList.contains("Energic")) {
    var result = allMusic.filter((x)=>x.style === "Energic");
    console.log(result);
  }
}

function filterName(x) {
  filterStatus = document.querySelector(".search-filter");
  if (x==1)
  {
      filterStatus.classList.toggle("Hip-Hop");
      filterByName();
  }
  if (x==2)
  {
      filterStatus.classList.toggle("Energic");
      filterByName();
  }
  if (x==3)
  {
      filterStatus.classList.toggle("Workout");
      filterByName();
  }
  if (x==4)
  {
      filterStatus.classList.toggle("Chill");
      filterByName();
  }
  if (x==5)
  {
      filterStatus.classList.toggle("Sad-Lofi");
      filterByName();
  }
  if (x==6)
  {
      filterStatus.classList.toggle("Rock");
      filterByName();
  }
}
```

json file aka database for searchbar/filter

```
  {
      name: "Havana",
      artist: "Camila Cabello",
      src: "CamilaCabelloHavana",
      img: "CamilaCabelloHavana",
      style: "Energic",
      status: "",
  },
  {
      name: "Dj Is Your Second Name",
      artist: "C-Bool , Giang Pham",
      src: "C-BooLDJ",
      img: "C-BooLDJ",
      style: "Energic",
      status: "",
  },
  {
      name: "Never Go Away",
      artist: "C-Bool",
      src: "C-BooL-NeverGoAway",
      img: "C-BooL-NeverGoAway",
      style: "Energic",
      status: "",
  },
  {
      name: "Champions",
      artist: "Kevin Rudolf",
      src: "KevinRudolf-Champions",
      img: "KevinRudolf-Champions",
      style: "Energic",
      status: "",
  },
  {
      name: "Ride It",
      artist: "DJ Regard",
      src: "DJRegard-Rideit",
      img: "DJRegard-Rideit",
      style: "Energic",
      status: "",
  },
```

```
  <div class="search-content">

    <h1>Czego szukasz?</h1>
    <div class="search-bar">
      <input type="text" id="search-item" placeholder="Wykonawcy, utwory" onkeyup="searchName()">
        <div class="clear-btn">
        <button type="button" id="clear-input-btn" onclick="ClearFields();searchName();"><i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i></button>
        </div>
   </div>

  </div>

  <div class="search-filter" id="filterBox">

      <div class="search-item" onclick="filterName(1)">
        <p>Hip-Hop</p>
      </div>
      <div class="search-item" onclick="filterName(2)">
        <p>Energiczna</p>
      </div>
      <div class="search-item" onclick="filterName(3)">
        <p>Workout</p>
      </div>
      <div class="search-item" onclick="filterName(4)">
        <p>Chill</p>
      </div>
      <div class="search-item" onclick="filterName(5)">
        <p>Sad-Lofi</p>
      </div>
      <div class="search-item" onclick="filterName(6)">
        <p>Rock</p>
      </div>

  </div>

  <div class="search-results">



  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Can you include your HTML?

Comment: Edited, sorry for that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even without seeing your HTML it seems like there is scope for a lot of improvements. For example the `filterName(x)` function can be written as

```
function filterName(x) {
 if(x>0&&x<7){
  document.querySelector(".search-filter").classList.toggle(
   ["Hip-Hop","Energic","Workout","Chill","Sad-Lofi","Rock"][x-1]);
  filterByName();
 }
}
```

The rest can probably also be simplified, but knowing your HTML would be the key here.

The `filterByName()` function is also dubious in the way that it prints out two separate, unrelated results: firstly the search results for "Hip-Hop" (if that was selected) and secondly those for "Energic". Is your intention to filter according to one or all given criteria? Assuming that the match of *one* filter criterion is sufficient you could do:

```
function filterByName() {
  const classList=[...document.querySelector(".search-filter").classList];
  console.log(allMusic.filter(t=>classList.contains(t.style))
}
```

Let us piece your code together into a working snippet:

```js
const allMusic = [
      {name: "Havana",artist: "Camila Cabello",src: "CamilaCabelloHavana",img: "CamilaCabelloHavana",style: "Energic",status: ""},
      {name: "Dj Is Your Second Name",artist: "C-Bool , Giang Pham",src: "C-BooLDJ",img: "C-BooLDJ",style: "Energic",status: ""},
      {name: "Never Go Away",artist: "C-Bool",src: "C-BooL-NeverGoAway",img: "C-BooL-NeverGoAway",style: "Energic",status: ""},
      {name: "Champions",artist: "Kevin Rudolf",src: "KevinRudolf-Champions",img: "KevinRudolf-Champions",style: "Energic",status: ""},
      {name: "Ride It",artist: "DJ Regard",src: "DJRegard-Rideit",img: "DJRegard-Rideit",style: "Hip-Hop",status: "" }];
const [search,filter,results] = ["#search-item",".search-filter",".search-results"].map(sel=>document.querySelector(sel));
results.innerHTML=allMusic.map((a,i)=>
`<li id="li${i}" onclick="clicked(this)">
  <div class="result-box">
   <div class="result-box-cover">
     <h1 class="result-name">${a.name}</h1>
     <p class="result-artist">${a.artist}</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <a href="songs/${a.src}.mp3">${a.src}.mp3</a>
 </li>`).join("\n");
// show which item was clicked:
function clicked(o){console.log("Index "+o.id+" was clicked.");}
// main filter function
function filterList(){
  // get all styles by collecting the textContent of .active buttons:
  let styles=[...filter.querySelectorAll(".active")].map(b=>b.textContent),
  // get current search string from input field:
    srch=search.value.toLowerCase();
  allMusic.forEach((m,i)=>{ // both conditions must be met: style and search pattern
    results.children[i].style.display=(m.name+"|"+m.artist).toLowerCase().includes(srch)&&styles.includes(m.style)?"":"none";
  })
}
// attach filterList() to input event of text-input and click event of style buttons:
search.addEventListener("input",filterList);
filter.onclick = ev =>{
 if(ev.target.tagName == "BUTTON"){ 
   ev.target.classList.toggle("active");
   filterList()
}};
// do initial filtering:
filterList()
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: #cec;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css">
<div class="search-content">
  <h1>Czego szukasz?</h1>
  <div class="search-bar">
    <input type="text" id="search-item" placeholder="Wykonawcy, utwory">
    <button type="button" id="clear-input-btn" onclick="search.value='';filterList()"><i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>

<br>
<div class="search-filter" id="filterBox">
  <button>Hip-Hop</button>
  <button>Energic</button>
  <button>Workout</button>
  <button>Chill</button>
  <button>Sad-Lofi</button>
  <button>Rock</button>
</div>
<div class="search-results"></div>
```

I took the liberty of rewriting some of your script to avoid repetitions and generally to make the code a little shorter and easier to maintain. I also changed the `<audio>` tags to `<a>` as they would have been invisible otherwise.

Comment: Hello, i tried ur version but i didnt work for me, i ubdated post with html. My version is working (kinda) im getting filter results but in console log im trying to make it visible in search-results and even eventually enable filter results to be visible/hidden when search input is being used. I hope i didnt misrepresent something.

Comment: Please check my answer again, I added a working snippet.